# Sonatype Nexus Migration

Tags: maven, migration, nexus, sonatype

I am trying to migrate repositories from multiple Nexus 2 and Nexus 3 instances into a single Nexus 3 instance.

While it is easy to perform migration of repositories from Nexus 2 to Nexus 3, I haven't found any solution to migrate repositories between two Nexus 3 instances as this version of Nexus stores data in blob stores.

Is there any solution for this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer is this is not currently possible.

Comment: However, I'll pop back in to this answer at some point in the next two weeks with hopefully some workaround for you.